# Best way to find duplicate lines in large string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

What is the best way to find duplicate lines (that repeats more than one time) in string that contains more than 10 M lines? (I just try to keep array as string to save memory)

For example:

**input**:

```
userId256
userId512
userId64
userId256
userId128
userId128
userId128
userId8
userId4
...
```

**output**:

```
userId256
userId128
```

I would use `split("\n")` and then work with array, but may be there is more optimum way to work with big string values.

### To get unique lines I used:

```
let result = Array.from(new Set(bigString.split("\n")))
        .join("\n")
        .toString();
```

Works fast for 10M lines. Is there any way to get deplicates using Set in JS?

Comment: This is in node.js? In like a 'readFile' context?

Comment: No, it's in browser. I'm using one social media's api to get user ids.

Comment: Ah, if it was in node through a file I'd potentially have a moderately better solution than splitting. In a browser, I'm not so sure

Comment: What is the actual goal? Find a list that has dupes?

Comment: Is your problem about the split method or working with the arrays?

Comment: @epascarello actual goal is to get list of ids thats repeat more than one time

Comment: So did you actually find an issue with memory or are you just assuming there is one?

Comment: @aksappy I'm trying to avoid to work with arrays, cuz of speed and memory

Comment: @epascarello, by design, the original string can have unlimited size, maybe there is no problem with an array up to 10M, but what if it gets 20M rows? I am trying to get fast work with the maximum available row size.

Comment: What are you going to do with the duplicate lines once you find them?  If you only care about the first occurrence, I'd actually turn the array into key/value pairs and since dictionaries only allow unique keys, that takes care of the uniqueness issue. Inversely, if you only care about the duplicates; add them to the dictionary and then take the ones that fail to be added; those are your duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid intermediate copies of the data, you could create a generator function that will hand you back an iterable:

```
function* split() {
  let re = /(^|\r?\n)(.*?)(?=(\r?\n|$))/g;
  for (;;) {
    const result = re.exec(data);
    if (result) {
      yield result[2];
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If I'm correctly understanding JavaScript regex, this will chip lines out of the big string, one at a time.

then you *could* supply this iterable as a parameter to the `Set` constructor for deduplication:

```
const deduped = new Set(split(data))
```

**However**, with the addition of a second generator function:

```
function* dedupe(iterable) {
  const s = new Set();
  for (const v of iterable) {
    if (!s.has(v)) {
      s.add(v);
      yield v;
    }
  }
}
```

It's now possible to prune duplicates from the get-go, rather than needing to build a monolithic set with many items, up-front.

So now you'd

```
 const theIterator = dedupe(split(data))
```

and you'd be able to pick through each one with a `for..of` loop (without the up-front cost of creating a huge set/array):

```
 for(const line of theIterator){
     // do something with line.
 }
```

### Edit (and shameless plug):

My library, [blinq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blinq), makes it easy to create a histogram from iterable data.

So

```
 import {blinq} from "blinq"
 //...
 const dataIterable = split(data)
 const histogram = 
     blinq(dataIterable)
         .groupBy(x => x)
         .select(g => ({key:g.key, count:g.count()}))
```

Comment: Thank you! Great idea to get unique elemnts! But how can I get the list of duplicates using generators?

Comment: I would make iterator and walk all lines and build a frequency table, like @jerch adviced.

Comment: @AlexKorzin I have [a library](https://github.com/biggyspender/blinq/) that provides some nice syntax for working with iterables: After creating the first iterator function, it would be as easy as `blinq(split(data)).groupBy(x=>x).select(g=>({key:g.key,count:g.count()}))` Take a look: https://github.com/biggyspender/blinq/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the performance is better, you'll need to check to profile it and compare with array based solutions.

You can use a RegExp with a [capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses), [positive lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) and a [back reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backreference) to find line that are repeated ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1fZ90E/1)). The result will be all lines that have a line with the same content after them.

However, if the lines are repeated more than twice (userId128 for example), the result will include all repetitions, but the last. To get only unique items, convert to a Set, and spread back to an array.

```js
const str = `userId256
userId512
userId64
userId256
userId128
userId128
userId128
userId8
userId4`

const result = [...new Set(str.match(/^(.+)$(?=[\s\S]+\1)/gm))]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I was thinking `+\1` was not supported with JavaScript, I was about to check it out but you beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

There isn't a way to magically identify the duplicates without accessing each element. Now it is a question of where you want to do it. This is particulary well done on a backend, since the user experience will not take a hit. If you still want it on the browser, you can use a `setTimeout` or use [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to reduce the impact on the user interface.

**Actual answer**

You must be able to use a reduce function for this.

```
const str = `your big string`;
const data = str.split("\n");
let duplicate = data.reduce((acc,currentValue,index, array) => {
  if(array.indexOf(currentValue)!=index && !acc.includes(currentValue)) acc.push(currentValue);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(`Duplicates are now in the array ${duplicate}`);
```

Comment: I am asking the user now =)

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends on what you wanna optimize for (time / space / code complexity) and on some circumstances:

- easy way:
  Walk all lines and do an exhaustive `indexOf` search. Whenever you get multiple results, memorize the line content. This almost needs no additional space, but has a bad runtime of O(n²).
- runtime optimized:
  Walk all lines and build a frequency table. Runs in O(n), but needs a temporary table object, where you count the occurences (worst case ~doubled space).
- mixture of both:
  Use a bloomfilter. Basically runs in O(n) (+some additional work if a match was found), and needs not much additional space. But note that bloomfilters are tricky to set up, with wrong storage size or bad hash functions it will drop back to O(n²). This has the highest code complexity, but might pay off for such a big amount of data. Beside that bloomfilter might perform poor, if the probability of duplicates is rather high.

Answer (score 0):

You can find duplicates by counting item and then filter by `count`:

```
const result = a.reduce((a, c)=> {
    a[c] = a[c] || {count: 0};
    a[c].count +=1;
    return a;
}, {});

const duplicates = Object.entries(result)
    .filter(([k, v]) => v.count > 1 )
    .map(([e])=> e);
```

An example:

```js
const a = [
        'userId256',
        'userId512',
        'userId64',
        'userId256',
        'userId128',
        'userId128',
        'userId128',
        'userId8',
        'userId4'
          ];

    const result = a.reduce((a, c)=> {
        a[c] = a[c] || {data:[]};
        a[c].data.push(c);
        return a;
    }, {});

    const duplicates = Object.entries(result)
        .filter(([k, v]) => v.data.length > 1 )
        .map(([e])=> e);


    console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd make a dictionary of the keys; and then the ones that fail to add are duplicates.

```
var f = myString.split('\n');
var dict = {};
for (i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
  if !(f[i] in dict) {
    dict.push({f[i] : 1});
  } else {

    //this is a duplicate, do with what you will.
    //in this, I'll just increment it.
    dict[f[i]] += 1;
  }
}
```